# I want to lerp my camera from one quaternion to another

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions

I want to achieve rotate the camera from original Quaternion to the target one.

Then i used the following code:

```
public class CameraMove : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public static bool start = false; 
    public Vector3 targetPosition;
    public Quaternion targetRotation;
    public float speed = 0.1f;

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(cameraRotate());
    }

    IEnumerator cameraRotate()
    {
        // Trigger cameraMove until clicking the sphere
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => start == true);
        while (transform.localRotation!=targetRotation)
        {
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.localRotation, targetRotation, speed * Time.deltaTime);
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

However, the camera didn't rotate at all, idk why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As alternative to [Ruzihm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57193296/7111561) I wanted to leave a solution here actually using `Lerp`.

The huge advantage of this is that you can additionally add ease-in and ease-out e.g. using [`Mathf.SmoothStep`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.SmoothStep.html) or even use other maths calculations in order to change the animation of the rotation.

It also allows you to control exactly how long the rotation will take independend how many degrees have to be rotated. In the example below I again calculated the duration by using your speed value in degrees per second but you could also simply e.g. pass a fixed duration like 1 or 2 seconds.

```c#
public class CameraMove : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public static bool start = false; 
    public Vector3 targetPosition;
    // it's easier to adjust euler angles instead
    public Vector3 targetRotation;

    // here now set the rotation speed in degrees / second
    public float speed = 90f;

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(cameraRotate());
    }

    private IEnumerator cameraRotate()
    {
        // Trigger cameraMove until clicking the sphere
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => start == true);

        var startRotation = transform.localRotation;
        var finalRotation = Quaternion.Euler(targetRotation);

        // angle difference / angle per second => duration in seconds
        var duration = Quaternion.Angle(startRotation, finalRotation) / speed;

        var timePassed = 0f;

        while (timPassed < duration)
        {
            // with this factor you get a linear rotation like using Quaternion.RotateTowards ...
            var lerpFactor = timPassed / duration;

            // ... Huge advantage: You can now add ease-in and ease-out to the rotation!
            var smoothedLerpFactor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, lerpFactor);

            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(startRotation, finalRotation, smoothedLerpFactor);

            // add to the timePassed avoiding overshooting
            timaPassed += Mathf.Min(duration - timePassed, Time.deltaTime);
            yield return null;
        }

        // to be sure set the rotation fixed when done
        transform.localRotation = finalRotation;
    }
}
```

---

For more awesome examples for the easing maths checkout [this post](https://chicounity3d.wordpress.com/2014/05/23/how-to-lerp-like-a-pro/)

e.g. as we had ease-in and ease-out:

```
var lerpFactor = passedTime / duration;
smoothedLerpFactor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, lerpFactor);
```

e.g. only ease-out

```
var lerpFactor = passedTime / duration;
smoothedLerpFactor = Mathf.Sin(lerpFactor * Mathf.PI * 0.5f);
```

e.g. only ease-in

```
var lerpFactor = passedTime / duration;
smoothedLerpFactor = 1f - Mathf.Cos(lerpFactor * Mathf.PI * 0.5f);
```

e.g. exponential ease in

```
var lerpFactor = passedTime / duration;
smoothedLerpFactor = lerpFactor * lerpFactor;
```

and you can also use them multiple times to even increase the smoothing effects like e.g. super smooth step ;)

```
var lerpFactor = passedTime / duration;
smoothedLerpFactor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, lerpFactor));
```

Comment: Thanks~ for your detailed answer, Learnt a lot on rotation

Comment: Great answer! What would you change if you had a different easing you wanted to use? That would be a change to the `var smoothedLerpFactor` line right?

Comment: exactly! Checkout [this post](https://chicounity3d.wordpress.com/2014/05/23/how-to-lerp-like-a-pro/). There are a lot of other easing maths examples you can use

Answer (score 1):

### Use [Quaternion.RotateTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.RotateTowards.html)

`Quaternion.Lerp` or `Quaternion.Slerp` are to be used when you always have a percentage of how far from the start you want to rotate. However, you have a current rotation and a goal rotation and a speed. This is better suited to using `Quaternion.RotateTowards`:

```
IEnumerator cameraRotate()
{
    // Trigger cameraMove until clicking the sphere
    yield return new WaitUntil(() => start);
    while (transform.localRotation != targetRotation)
    {
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.localRotation, 
                targetRotation, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, i checked it still cannot work. I am thinking about the my targetRotation is the correct value. This is the (x,y,z) value i inspected from inspector, is that correct?

Comment: x,y,z is the euler representation of Quaternion, but you can't use those values directly as quaternions x,y,z,w

Comment: @ChenJi try to rather use a `public Vector3 targetRotation` (more easy to adjust euler angles) and in `RotateTowards` use `Quaternion.Euler(targetRotation)`. Or even more efficient store this values once before the loop begins ;)